# Java Custom Annotation using another annotation

Tags: java, powermock, java-11

Because of problems with Powermock and Java 11, we have had to use the @PowerMockIgnore on all our test classes.

```
@PowerMockIgnore({ "javax.management.*", "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*", "javax.xml.*",
        "org.xml.*", "org.w3c.dom.*", "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.*", "javax.activation.*" })
```

In order to avoid duplicating this in all test classes, we created a custom annotation to be used instead that had this PowerMockIgnore defined on one place.
So that all we would need in all our test classes would be

```
@SuppressPowerMockInitError
```

However: This custom annotation does not seem to work.

```
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PowerMockIgnore;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD })
@Inherited
@Documented
@PowerMockIgnore({ "javax.management.*", "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*", "javax.xml.*",
        "org.xml.*", "org.w3c.dom.*", "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.*", "javax.activation.*" })
public @interface SuppressPowerMockInitError {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like it is possible to achieve this with annotations.

However creating an abstract class that has this common annotation seems like the best way to achieve this.

```
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PowerMockIgnore;

@PowerMockIgnore({ "javax.management.*", "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*", "javax.xml.*",
        "org.xml.*", "org.w3c.dom.*", "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.*", "javax.activation.*" })
public abstract class AbstractPowerMockTest {

}
```